# GET request iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, request

```
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="send">Request</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("send"),
    div = document.getElementById('result');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var result = createIframe("f", "/lorem.txt");
    console.log(result.contentWindow);
    div.innerHTML = result.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
});

function createIframe(name, src, debug) {
    var tmpElem = document.createElement('div');

    tmpElem.innerHTML = '<iframe name="' + name + '" id="' + name + '" src="' + src + '">';
    var iframe = tmpElem.firstChild;
    iframe.style.display = 'none';

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    return iframe;
}
```

I have on the local server is a file lorem.txt. With hidden frame I am trying to query the contents of this file and paste it into `<div id="result"></div>`. But for some reason it does not is inserted. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe elements with the ids of `"send"` and `"result"`, respectively do not exist at the moment when your javascript code is running, therefore the `click` event will not be attached to the `button`. You need to make sure that these elements exist when you try to get them by their ids or attach events to them.

Solution: Either make sure your code is running after the document has been loaded or put your relevant script tag below the html you have described in your question.

Comment: JS code wrapped in window.onload - nothing has changed.

Comment: If you have this at the start of your code: console.log(document.getElementById("send")) what does it print into the browser console?

Comment: `<div id="result"></div>`

Comment: Again: Modify your Javascript code and write console.log(document.getElementById("send")); before the initializations. Run the code. What will be typed into the console of the browser (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)? By the way: are you SURE your script is loaded into the page?

Comment: Displays element div.

Comment: It is impossible, since the parameter was "send". The result you described would be expectable if you called console.log() with "result", but you called it with "send"

Comment: I somehow do not quite understand. Look at the screenshot, which I have attached: [screenshot](http://savepic.su/5650635.png).

What's wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78112/discussion-between-lajos-arpad-and-aleksandr-aleksandrov).

Comment: I was helped: loaded into DIV necessary event onload iframe, instead of at once when it is created, it is empty at the moment.